# Android Studio 3.1 No space left on device

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, linux-mint

After trying every solution I could find I still can't install an sdk.
The specific one is 
**Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image** 
under the `Android 6.0 (marshmellow) sdk`

> The error it throws is:

An error occurred while preparing `SDK` package Google APIs `Intel x86 Atom_64`  System Image: No space left on device.

I'm running Linux Mint 18.3 cinnamon 64-bit with 8GB RAM and 250GB free space on my drive
So far I've tried increasing ALL the filesystems under df -h to 8GB
as I do not have a /tmp one specifically (appears to be under my root filesystem)

```
$ df -h

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            8.0G     0  8.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs           8.0G  9.3M  8.0G   1% /run
/dev/sda1       290G   51G  225G  19% /
tmpfs           8.0G   13M  8.0G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           8.0G  4.0K  8.0G   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           8.0G     0  8.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
cgmfs           8.0G     0  8.0G   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs           8.0G   44K  8.0G   1% /run/user/1000
```

(the normal output sizes are 3.9GB or 700MB for the last one)

```
$ df -i

Filesystem       Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev            1003060    483  1002577    1% /dev
tmpfs           1009966    710  1009256    1% /run
/dev/sda1      19283968 506873 18777095    3% /
tmpfs           1009966     29  1009937    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1009966      6  1009960    1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1009966     19  1009947    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
cgmfs           1009966     15  1009951    1% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs           1009966     31  1009935    1% /run/user/1000
```

I've also tried relocating java tmp location with
    **export _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/tmp**
and also putting this in the `studio.sh` file (apparently this doesn't work as of studio 3.x)
tried plenty of restarts too
I'm doing this for React Native development
Also if there is a better place to post this let me know.
Thanks

Comment: Edit your question and append the output of `df -h` and `df -i`.

Comment: Hey Daniel, it's very frustrating, I'm facing the same problem! I'm running Mint Mate 18.3 and the only way to make it work is installing sdk package manually: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-atom-x86-image-for-android-4-4-kitkat-installation-instructions-manually (follow Mac OSX solution)